# Jquery animate fontSize back to original size on click

Tags: jquery, function, click, jquery-animate

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4bn2bvjc/)**

```
$("button").click(function(){
$("h1").animate({fontSize: "50px"});
```

How to make the font size return to its original size if clicked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by checking the current font size and then toggle the value to set, like this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("h1").animate({
    fontSize: $('h1').css('font-size') == '32px' ? "50px" : '32px'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<h1>HELLO</h1>
```

That said, it would be better practice (and result in a smoother effect) to do the transition in CSS and just toggle the class on the element in your JS code, like this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("h1").toggleClass('large');
})
```

```css
h1 { transition: all 0.5s; }
.large { font-size: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<h1>HELLO</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. However using both methods the transition is a slightly a bit jerky or laggy or stuttery.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it CSS based, which makes the JS part less:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 $("h1").toggleClass('size-50');
})
```

```css
.size-50{
    font-size:50px;
}
h1{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;.toggle
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
CLICK
</button>

<h1>
HELLO
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. However, the transition is a slightly a bit jerky or laggy or stuttery.